# Custom Android Screensaver (or sleep screen)

Tags: android

I need to build a custom android screen saver so anoboy could explain me how to create an activity that will be launched instead of the default screensaver which show only basic informations as Network, DateTime and alarms...

Tanks for ur help!

Comment: Aren't you using up your battery by running a screensaver?

Comment: @DOK Not if you are plugged into a power source?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean creating your own lock screen, there is no provision for this in the Android SDK.

Comment: Well so what about custom screen lock in HTC Hero which display a MP3 player when music is on or the flyscreen(http://www.myflyscreen.com/) application that do exactly what i want like showing rss feeds aso...

I'm looking for examples, snippets, documentation that help make my own custom screen lock.
I found another one called ContactOwner(http://sites.google.com/site/paranoidandroidproject/) that is open source but this application just change the alarm part of the screen lock to personnal text informations. 
I would like to change the whole running activity

Comment: That's a completely custom lock screen and system that HTC have built outside of the Android SDK.  They have made numerous platform modifications, so that's essentially what you would have to do if you wanted to be able to customise things in the same way.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to create a custom lock screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261388/android-screen-saver-sample-code/5261452#5261452

Comment: @dbyrne: But in your own words this "is a hack". In my words "there is no provision for this in the Android SDK." :)

Answer (score 1):

Although its not something I would recommend, it is possible to create a custom lock screen. Please see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261388/android-screen-saver-sample-code/5261452#5261452).