# Android code for screen Saver

Tags: android, screensaver

I am looking for a sample code on Android Screen Saver. I tried Google but hard to find any useful result. Does anyone have any good samples on that? please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Screen Saver Sample Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261388/android-screen-saver-sample-code)

Answer (score 1):

i searched and is this what you are looking for? 
https://github.com/Dustinmj/packages-experimental-DreamTheater

Answer (score 1):

In android lock screen acts as screen saver. If you want to use any other animation as screen saver in place of default lock screen, try about **how to create custom lock screen ?**

If you are looking for screen saver of normal PCs, you have to modify/create the Home Screen App to add this screen saver feature. I think no concept of screen saver till android 2.3.3. I don't know about after 2.3.3.

I hope it may help you.