# How to customize Screen Saver in android?

Tags: android, screen, screensaver

Is it possible to customize the screen saver in android ? May be this question is duplicate of [Android Screen Saver Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261388/android-screen-saver-sample-code) . but i am not getting any useful answer for it. I am not talking about "Lock Screen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android lock screen acts as screen saver. If you want to use any other animation as screen saver in place of default lock screen, try about how to create custom lock screen ?

If you are looking for screen saver of normal PCs, you have to modify/create the Home Screen App to add this screen saver feature. I think no concept of screen saver till android 2.3.3. I don't know about after 2.3.3.

Comment: I want to give animation in the screen when its in idle mode. I know about Lock screen, its having different meaning.