# Creating screensaver using nativeInterface

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I am trying to change the screensaver on android phone using codenameone, so for that, I'm using native interface process,

I then create my main class and then after I create "MyNativeContent" that inherits from NativeInterface,

here is the content:
package com.faugan.addscreen;

```
import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

/**
 *
 * @author ccpita
 */
public interface MyNativeContent extends NativeInterface{
    public void testAndroidNatif();
}
```

now I make a right click on my interface to generate native access for all platform,

then after I open MyNativeContentImpl.java from my android directory and I do this inside:

```
package com.faugan.addscreen;

public class MyNativeContentImpl {
    public void testAndroidNatif() {
        // code for screensaver on android
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now when i compile this, it fails and i am having this errors:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.faugan.addscreen.MyNativeContentImpl
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1001)
>       at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:100)
>       at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:50)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>       at com.codename1.system.NativeLookup.create(NativeLookup.java:81)
>       at com.faugan.addscreen.MyApplication.lambda$start$0(MyApplication.java:47)
>       at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3260)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2651)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3239) Rendering frame took too long 722 milliseconds
>       at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2025)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1070)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:999)
>       at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
>       at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.faugan.addscreen.MyApplication.lambda$start$0(MyApplication.java:48)
>       at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3260)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2651)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3239)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2025)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1070)
>       at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:999)
>       at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
>       at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

Now my questions are:

1) while I am having these errors? is it because this is running in a simulator?

2) can you tell me what to put in the `testAndroidNatif()` method to change the screensaver on android phones?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should start by creating `MyNativeContent` interface that extends `NativeInterface`, then right-click on it and select **Generate Native Access**.

Switch to Files tab and expand the folder `native` -> `android` -> `com` -> `faugan` -> `addscreen`. Then open `MyNativeContentImpl.java` file, this is where all your Android native codes will be added.

You can add more android files in this folder and reference them in  `MyNativeContentImpl.java` file. Remember to return true in the `isSupported()` method of `MyNativeContentImpl`.

As for your second question, this is Android specific which you have to do on your own or ask on StackOverflow with `android` and `java` tags or search around on `sample codes to change screensaver from an Android App`. Take a look at this question on SO for instance... [android-screen-saver-sample-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261388/android-screen-saver-sample-code/5261452#5261452)

Comment: For the first question, i am still having the error, but for the second one, the link you sent, i just see an xml content as code, how can i integrate that in codenameone? i don't know native android coding, can you please give an example in which you use codenameone and integrate android native code inside? Thanks