# How to set application as screen saver in android?

Tags: android

hey hi,
i had created an simple digital clock application. I want to display this application as screen saver. In other words want to launch this application automatically when the system is idle for a specific time duration. The theme i had applied on my application doesn't allow title bar and status bar. Hence, it cover the complete screen but i don't know how to launch it as screen saver or detect idle system and record system idle time to launch my application automatically when an certain time limit is crossed.
thanks in advance....
Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this two answers

[Custom Android Screensaver (or sleep screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134458/custom-android-screensaver-or-sleep-screen)

[Android Screen Saver Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261388/android-screen-saver-sample-code/5261452#5261452)

Comment: is it possible to test this on emulator.

Comment: why do you send to "answers" that do NOT answer