# Screen Saver in android sceen locks

Tags: android

I want to start an animation in the form of screen saver when the screen is locked or when the screen sleeps.

any one help me for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not any provision lock screen saver in Android sdk.

For more visit this answer

[Custom Android Screensaver (or sleep screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134458/custom-android-screensaver-or-sleep-screen)